# dropdown dependent jquery input in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, dependencies, drop-down-menu

ok so now i have a working dropdown dependent forms,, example if i choose item 1 in dropdown some div would appear and if i choose item 2 some other div would appear.. my problem is that even the other div is hidden, it will still get the post values of the hidden input types in a div.. is there a way in which if a div is hidden, its posts input would not be submitted?

here is my jquery

```
$(function() {
    $(".forms").hide();
    $("#myselect").change(function() {
        switch($(this).val()){ 
            case "student":
                $(".forms").hide().parent().find("#Form1").show();
                break;
            case "teacher":
                $(".forms").hide().parent().find("#Form2").show();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

here is my view

```
<form>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="student">student</option>
  <option value="teacher">teacher</option>
</select>

<div id="Form1" class="forms">
//some input here like <input type="text" name="studentName"/>
</div>

<div id="Form2" class="forms">Form 2 Contents</div>
//some input here like <input type="text" name="teacherName"/>
</form>
```

**EDIT**
i have tried this one using .remove(). but it still reads the posts data from #student_profile

```
$(function() {
    $(".fields").hide();
    $("#role").change(function() {
        switch($(this).val()){ 
            case "3":
                $(".fields").hide().parent().find("#student_profile").show();
                break;
            case "2":
                $(".fields").hide().parent().find("#teacher_profile").show();
                 $("#student_profile").remove();

                break;
            }
        });
    });
```

**EDIT** heres my real code

```
<form action="add" method="post" class="form label-inline uniform" />


<h3><a href="#">User</a></h3>
                    <div class="field"><label for="username">Username </label> <input id="username" name="username" size="50" type="text" class="medium" /></div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="password">Password </label> <input id="password" name="password" size="50" type="password" class="medium" /></div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="role">Role </label>
                        <select id="role" name="role" class="medium">

                            <optgroup label="Type of User">
                                <option value="3" />Student
                                <option value="2" />Teacher
                                <option value="1"/>Admin
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div id="student_profile" class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                                <label for="type">Course</label>
                                <select id="type" name="stdntCourse" class="medium">
                                    <optgroup  label="Choose Course">
                                        <option value="BS IT" />BS IT
                                        <option value="BS CS" />BS CS
                                        <option value="BS IS" />BS IS
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="type">Year</label>
                                <select id="type" name="stdntYear" class="medium">
                                    <optgroup  label="Student Year">
                                        <option value="1st" />1st
                                        <option value="2nd" />2nd
                                        <option value="3rd" />3rd
                                        <option value="4th" />4th
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>



                    </div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="regdate">Registration Date </label> <input id="regdate" name="regdate" size="20" type="text" class="large" /></div>
<br />
<h3><a href="#">User Profile</a></h3>

                    <div class="field"><label for="fname">First Name </label> <input id="fname" name="fname" size="50" type="text" class="large" /></div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="fname">Middle Name </label> <input id="mname" name="mname" size="50" type="text" class="large" /></div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="lname">Last Name </label> <input id="lname" name="lname" size="50" type="text" class="large" /></div>                    

                    <div class="field"><label for="nickname">Nickname</label> <input id="nickname" name="nickname" size="50" type="text" class="large" /></div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="birthday">Birthday</label> <input type="text" size="20" name="birthday" id="birthday" class="large"/></div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="type">Sex</label>
                        <select id="type" name="sex" class="medium">
                            <optgroup>
                                <option value="M" />Male
                                <option value="F" />Female
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="address">Address</label> <input id="address" name="address" size="50" type="text" class="large" /></div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="city" class="">City </label> <input id="city" name="city" size="20" type="text" class="medium" /></div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="country" class="">Country </label> <input id="country" name="country" size="20" type="text" class="medium" /></div>

                    <div class="field"><label for="zcode">Zip Code </label> <input id="zcode" name="zcode" size="20" type="text" class="medium" /></div>


                    <!--                    
                    <div class="field clearfix">                                
                        <label for="lname">File Upload </label>                                 
                        <input style="opacity: 0;" class="file" type="file" />                              
                    </div>
                    ---->



            <!----    
                    <div class="controlset field">
                        <span class="label">Preferred Location</span>


                        <div class="controlset-pad">
                        <input name="radio1" id="radio1" value="1" type="radio" /> <label for="radio1">Option 1</label><br />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <input name="radio1" id="radio2" value="1" type="radio" /> <label for="radio2">Option 2</label><br />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <input name="radio1" id="radio3" value="1" type="radio" /> <label for="radio3">Option 3</label><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>          

                    <div class="controlset field">

                        <span class="label">Something Else </span>
                        <div class="controlset-pad">
                            <input name="approved" id="check1" value="1" type="checkbox" />  <label for="check1">Some Option 1</label><br />
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <input name="pending" id="check2" value="1" type="checkbox" />  <label for="check2">Some Option 2</label><br />
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <input name="actives" id="check3" value="1" type="checkbox" /> <label for="check3">Some Option 3</label><br />

                        </div>
                    </div>  


                    <div class="field"><label for="description">Description</label> <textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="description" name="description"></textarea></div>

                    <br />
        ---->   

                    <div class="buttonrow">
                        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-black" value="Reset"/>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-grey" value="Add User"/>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bksk7/2/

## Explanation

Basically what you need to understand when doing this kind of technique is that unless you put the fields on different forms it'll always submit the fields when you press the `input` with the submit `type` on it.

To solve this, you need to use JavaScript to take over the functionality that the `submit` has. Doing this is simple as setting up a `click` listener with a `.preventDefault()` which will, as the name implies, prevent the default functionality of that button.

After that you need to take figure out what elements to send and pass the data to `$.ajax`, and you're done :)

You can even take the chance to do some nice validation with that approach if you wish.

Hope it helps

Solved here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bksk7/2/

Related documentation:

$.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: my mind is toasted.. lol.. actually there are many fields in my form,, like username,etc... looks like a daunting tasks for me..@_@ thanks though.. i appreciated your effort..

Comment: I can't believe you can't use the solution I gave you when it's just simple. I'm going to update it so you can see how to include the rest of the possible fields you could have.

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Bksk7/2/ You can add all the other fields to the base; and they should be sended acordingly

Comment: have tried your updated code, chose student yet the value returned was `name=dsa&something=das&studentName=adsd&teacherName=` where teacherName should not be returned because i didnt chose teacher

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing unwanted inputs with jQuery? (http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: tried that one but i cant get it to work.. i have edited my posts see my code please.

Answer (score 0):

some input here like:

```
<input type="text" name="teacherName"/>`
```

this part of the code is outside your div:

```
<div id="Form2" class="forms">Form 2 Contents</div>
```

that's why you can't hide it

and try to target every `.forms` like that

```
$(function() {   
   $(".forms").hide();   
   $("#myselect").change(function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
    switch($(this).val()){

        case "student":
            $(".forms").each(function(){

                $(this).hide();
            });
            $("#Form1").show();
            break;
        case "teacher":
            $(".forms").each(function(){

                $(this).hide();
            });
            $("#Form2").show();
            break;
       }
   });

});
```